# try to remove iframe id with query while click like facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

am try to remove div when click like

my code

```
<div id="closebox"  style="position: absolute;margin-right: 2px; opacity: 0;/* width:27px; */ /* height: 20px; */ /* overflow: hidden; */ width: 47px; height: 20px; overflow: hidden; right: 202px; bottom: 15px;"> 

<iframe id="closebox1" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/0000000&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=60&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=31" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:45px; margin-top:3px;padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px; height:31px; z-index: 0; /* position: absolute; */opacity: 0;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

</div>  

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">نعم </button> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#closebox1').click(function () { 
   $('#closebox1').hide();    
});
</script>
```

i need when click into div id `closebox` or `closebox1` remove iframe id `closebox1`

not working because click here it's into iframe content it's like botton not div

Comment: Your title is conflicting with what you're writing in the question.

Comment: simply i need to remove iframe when click like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not posible with iframe like button if you use any other button it's work with your code but iframe into div it's not posible to click div because iframe take click on behalf of div.
if you click your button tag and remove iframe it's posible to remove iframe.

like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.btn-default').click(function () { 
        $('#closebox1').remove()  
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('#closebox, #closebox1').click(function(){
    $('#closebox1').hide();
});
```

That will hide the iframe when clicking on #closebox or #closebox1

Alternatively, do something similar but instead of hiding the iframe, change the 'src' attribute.

Comment: not working   <script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#closebox, #closebox1').click(function(){
    $('#closebox1').hide();
    $('#closebox2').hide();
    $('#closebox3').hide();
});
    });

</script>

Comment: not working because click here it's into iframe content it's like botton not div

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#closebox").click(function(){
   $(this).children("iframe").remove();
});
```

Please Try This one.

Comment: not working because click here it's into iframe content it's like botton not div